# navbar hamburger not working [react-tailwindcss]

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, navbar

I'm fairly new to react development, and I was experimenting a bit with tailwindcss. I'm trying to build a small example of a navbar for mobile, but the transition from the right isn't smooth.

I've looked forums, and other answers here, yet none of them work in my case.

This is the navbar component:
it tried to add functionality to my hamburger in a navbar nut its not working, though it appear fine on large screen but the menu not opening on small devices
Here's a code sample
Toggle mobile navbar using hamburger menu
Code:

````
const Menu = ({isOpen}) => {
  return (
    <ul className={`flex-1 flex justify-center items-center gap-16 max-lg:hidden ${isOpen ? ("flex") : (" hidden md:flex")}`}>
  {navLinks.map((item) => (
    <li key={item.label}>
      <a href={item.href}
      className="block md:inline-block font-montserrat leading-normal text-lg text-slate-gray">
        {item.label}
      </a>
    </li>   
  ))}
</ul>
  )
}

const Nav = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <header className="padding-x py-8 absolute z-10 w-full">
        <nav className="flex justify-between items-center max-container">
          <a href="#">
           <img src={headerLogo} alt="Nike logo" width={130} height={29}/>
          </a>
          <div className="hidden max-lg:block">
          <button
         onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
         className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 rounded-full text-black-500 hover:text-black-400" >
         <svg
           className={`fill-current h-3 w-3 ${isOpen ? "hidden" : "block"}`}
          >
         </svg>
         <svg
           className={`fill-current h-3 w-3 ${isOpen ? "block" : "hidden"}`}
         >
         </svg>
       </button>
      </div>
      {isOpen && <Menu isOpen={isOpen}/> }
        </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Nav```
 


[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d75Rt.jpg)

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong or a hint is greatly appreciated.
````

Comment: What do you think you have done already to make it smooth?  "I've looked forums, and other answers here, yet none of them work in my case." isn't helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have provided you with a codesandbox that runs my navbar I use. I don't know why it's broken like that in codesandbox but it still does the trick. For smooth transitions in your navbar you need to use useTransition and fill it in with the animations you want the element to have. Then you will make an animated div:

```
{/* MENU MASK */}
{maskTransitions((style, item) =>
    item && (
        <animated.div
            style={style}
            className="relative fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full z-50"
        >

        </animated.div>
    )
)}
{/* Mobile Menu */}
{menuTransitions((style, item) =>
    item && (
        <animated.div
            style={style}
            className="fixed bg-indigo-800 top-0 left-0 w-4/5 h-full z-100 shadow"
        >
            <img className="max-w-full h-auto p-5" src={logo} alt="Logo" />
            <ul className="p-5 text-3xl text-white">
                <li><Link to="/" className="border-b border-t py-3 block hover:underline" onClick={() => setShowMenu(false)}>Home</Link></li>
                <li
                    onClick={() => setShowDropdown(!showDropdown)}
                    className="border-b py-3 block"
                >
                    <span>Projecten</span>
                    {dropIcon}
                    {dropdownTransitions((style, item) =>
                        item && (
                            <animated.div
                                style={style}
                                className="relative bg-indigo-800 top-full left-0 w-full z-50 shadow"
                            >
                                {dropdownContent}
                            </animated.div>
                        )
                    )}
                </li>
                <li><Link to="/info" className="border-b py-3 block hover:underline" onClick={() => setShowMenu(false)}>FAQ</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </animated.div>
    )
)}
```

Note: I have added maskTransition as well so that when you open the mobile menu that spans like 75/80% of the width, you will have an underlaying layer that is black with see through opacity for a better looking effect.

Navbar example with transitions:
[image: Edit ecstatic-bell-mvl7q9]